# Converse, Contrapositive and Negation

Tags: logic

If every printer is busy then there is a job in the queue.

where $B(p)$ = Printer $p$ is busy and $Q(j)$ = Print job $j$ is queued.

When it's translated to symbol, we'll have $(∀p B(p)) → (∃j Q(j))$.

I'm trying to translate this statement to both **English** and **symbol** forms for **Converse**, **Contrapositive** and **Negation**

Following is what i have got so far:
**Converse**
in words: If there is a job in the queue, then every printer is busy.
in symbol: $(∃j Q(j)) → (∀p B(p))$

**Contrapositive**
 
in words: If there is no job in the queue, then not every printer is busy.
in symbol: $¬(∃j Q(j)) → ¬(∀p B(p))$

**Negation**
 
in words: Every printer is busy and there is no job in the queue.
 
in symbol: (not sure)

It's the symbol part that i'm not sure if they are correct or not. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so we can see what bother you?

Comment: See [Converse, Inverse, Contrapositive](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/converse-inverse-contrapositive). "Cook it" with the fact that $\lnot \forall$ is equiv to $\exists \lnot$ and $\lnot \exists$ is equiv to $\forall \lnot$.

Comment: [Converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) of "if P, then Q" is "if Q, then P". Quite easy... "If there is a job in the queue, then every printer is busy".

Comment: [Contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of "if P, then Q" is "if not-Q, then not-P". Quite easy again... "If there is **no** job in the queue, then **not** every printer is busy".

Comment: Note that while an implication and its contrapositive are equivalent, an implication is not equivalent to its converse.

Comment: Hi Guys, I've manage to edit the question, providing the work that i've come out with so far. Please have a look and do let me know if i get it wrong.

Comment: Good progress.  How do you formalize "every printer is busy" and "there is no jobi in the queue?" (You've translataed both already.  So, what's stopping you from completing the negation part?)

Comment: Hi, Fabio, it may sound silly but it's the translating "implies" part to negation itself bothers me. My guess for negation in symbol would be (∀pB(p)) ∩ (∀j¬Q(j)) . Not sure if it's correct or not.

Comment: You need to use $\wedge$ instead of $\cap$.